# Is the corporate video game development industry habitable?

Tags: game-industry

After a bit of research, I realized that almost every article about video game development portrays the industry in a terrible light. In these articles, companies abuse workers with unpaid overtime. Developers are left out to dry when studios fall. Developers have a terrible quality of life, and few stay on board for very long (10 or more years).

What are the real working conditions actually like (regular 40-50 hour work weeks, stability, treated well, ect.)? Are there any statistics about job satisfaction in the in game development industry?

Comment: I'd like to make sure this isn't a poll for developers to sound off saying how content they are with their jobs. Answers would preferably include hard statistics about the industry as a whole, not an individual perspective about their current situation.

Comment: While I think it's possible we might get good answers to this question, I'm still more than a little leery of the question itself, as it seems explicitly geared towards 'discussion, not answers' and is decidedly 'opinion-based' (phrases like "content" and "treated well" are virtually impossible to evaluate in any objective sense, and "abuse" and "terrible quality of life" both suggest strong opinions on the questioner's part).

Comment: Maybe this question would also be relevant to http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ultimately, I want to know how many developers out there fail to treat employees like any employee should be treated. You're right, that cannot be measured objectively. However, statistics such as the number of employees working unpaid overtime or getting laid off can be measured objectively, and would more than suffice to answer my question.

Comment: The best answer I think you can find is the IGDA quality of life SIG and their whitepaper from 2004.  While there may be other studies, I'm not aware of them.  Here's a link to the IGSA site in case you missed it in my post:  http://www.igda.org/quality-life

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I’ve been working in the industry professionally for 15 years across a variety of companies and on multiple continents.    The work environment all comes down to being in a position to choose the right company and/or right project.  Some are good, some are bad.  There are always signs which can inform which a company/project is likely to be before you go to work there. Unfortunately, knowing which companies/projects are being run well requires a degree of skill and insight you can often only get by working in the industry and working for a bad, or at least poor, company.

While you do see news about bad situations get a lot of publicity, if you start doing the math on the number of companies/projects receiving publicity vs. the total number of development companies, perceptions about the number of good vs. bad companies/projects changes.

**Edit:**

If anyone wants to check out some empirical data, look up the IGDA quality of life SIG and whitepaper.  Here’s a link to get you started: http://www.igda.org/quality-life

Additionally, here are a number of questions I ask companies when trying to decide whether their development environment and methodology might be a good fit.  Under each I’ve listed reasons for asking the questions and/or answers which might increase my concerns.  Of course this is highly subjective and a negative answer to one question shouldn’t be an immediate deal breaker or a sign that a company/project would be a bad place to work.

If others have good interview questions which can inform people about the quality of life potential feel free to edit and add them or post them in the comments.

***At what stage of development is the project?***

This is generic feeler question which helps interpret answers to all of the other questions.  One reason I like to ask it as it allows me to layer my own definitions of terms like prototype, production, vertical slice, alpha, beta, etc. onto the company’s.  This helps me see whether my definitions match the company’s, and potentially see if they are overly optimistic about the state of a game.

***What is the estimated release date?***

If you have a chance to see the game demoed, you can frequently get a good idea about the amount of work required to complete it.  If a company tells you a game needs to ship in 6 months, and it looks like it has a tremendous amount of work left to complete, the chances are much higher than you are looking at a crunch situation to get it out the door.

***How was the release date determined?  Is it based on publisher/company requirements to ship a game within a certain timeframe?  Is it based on the projected time to complete a list of required features?***

This question helps give an idea about how firm a game’s ship date is.  Suppose a game is a licensed IP tied to a movie and the game’s release needs to be concurrent with the movie’s launch.  It is unlikely the game’s release date will be pushed back.  If the game seems like it needs a lot of work to get it out the door, the chances are high that a lot of crunch will be required to meet the launch deadline.
Alternatively, if a game is being developed to a certain number of features or a certain quality bar, and a company is particularly well funded, the risks of crunch go down (as long as the money keeps flowing).

***What is the company’s/project’s current headcount, how has it grown in the past and how do you expect it to grow in the future?***

I like this question as it can provide a lot of information about how much work is required to finish a game.  If you look at some recent MMORPGs, they have hired a tremendous number of contract developers late in the project.  The contractors were required to produce a prodigious volume of content in a relatively short amount of time.  If a project has added a tremendous number of people, and needs to add a lot more, it increases the likelihood that the team will be working long hours to complete all of the work required.

The inverse can also hold true.  If a project has a small team, an epic scope and only minimal hires planned, it can be a sign that they are trying to do a lot more with a lot less.

Of course, rapid hiring is not a firm indication a team will need to crunch long hours.  Rapid hiring can be due to a company’s success and the hires are needed to fuel to companies increased growth.

***What are your personal thoughts on crunch?***

This is pretty much self-explanatory.

***Have you had any situations where key milestone features were slipping and milestone deadlines were likely to be missed?  How did you handle it?***

This is a useful question as it asks for a situation where crunch could have occurred, yet does not specifically ask ‘do you crunch’.  How they answer will give you a good idea about how similar issues will be resolved going forward.

***What process is used to determine which features are going to be added to the game and how does a potential feature become a candidate for inclusion?***

I personally like this question as it can give an idea about how prone a company/project is to feature creep.  Rampant feature creep is a risk factor, especially when coupled with fixed deadlines as it increases the potential for crunch and/or buggy/unfinished games.

***How much experience does the company/team/leadership have in making  games?***

This question can often be answered through a bit of research and doesn’t need to be asked directly.  The more experience a team’s key leaders/ staff have with a particular genre, the more confidence you can have that they know the work required to release their game and, theoretically, will have planned features/headcounts/timelines appropriately.

***Does the project have milestones?  If so, how long are the milestones and how are milestone features and goals determined?  How often are all the milestone goals met?***

Milestones, and the ability for a project to hit them, are a great indicator of how well development is tracking.  If a company tells you they consistently miss milestone deadlines, or need to drop features from the milestone deliverables, that can be a cause for concern.  If that project has a fixed release date it is an especially high risk factor as the team will need to drop features from the release list or crunch to have all features in the shipping game.

***Do you schedule specific bug fixing times?***

Personally I have always felt that regularly scheduled bug fixing periods are very important to a project.  Formal bug fixing periods help ensure that issues are fixed as opposed to sweeping all of the bugs under a rug and ignoring them until the last minute.

Comment: @Byte56 That was why I tried to write my response using a more 'individual homework is required' rather than 'I've worked for X companies, Y were great and Z completely sucked'.

Comment: Just a suggestion for adding references or something similar. Thanks. I think your answer is good (but it could be better :))

Comment: Fantastic answer, Arconath. Very useful to those looking for a good working environment (and applicable to more than just games).

Comment: Thanks. A former colleague is in the process of finding a new job and a lot of what I wrote is based on recent conversations where I was trying to help him decide between a couple different companies.

Comment: +1 I really do appreciate the industry advice. As an outsider looking in, nuggets of information and advice like these are priceless.

However, is the 2004 IGDA survey data still relevant now, nearly 10 years later? I hope to God that the industry has managed to make those numbers look better than they did ~9-10 years ago.

Comment: @Sparkz63 Honestly, I always thought that survey was overly harsh on the industry, and that most of the negative responses were high by a good 10-20% (absolute values).  Of course, I have no data to back up that belief except my own personal observations and those from friends.  My gut would tell me that the industry has improved over the years, but I can’t back that up with any factual evidence.